# Twitter Bootstrap 3 - Affix Top Navigation bar is not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 3 framework. Look at this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9uMNy/3/) and you'll understand my problem.

1. Affix is not working properly.
2. Navigation Items are not in horizontal.

Please help me in resolving this issue.

And one more help, if there's any bootstrap classes list available that'd help me too.

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div class="container" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100" id="nav">
    <div class="navbar well">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                     <ul class="nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                     </ul>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Its horizontal for me. If you open bootstrap with NetBeans, it shows you all classes

Comment: I don't see the problem. Nav items are horizontal here. Affix can't working since there are no div's to refer to.

Comment: Sorry - I've updated it. Please check. Bootstrap 2 was added prior. Now i've added bootstrap 3.

Comment: Dan - I've downloaded NetBeans and Installed it. I've even opened that file and it's still a normal css file. How do I get the classes list out of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, for the menu, you shouldn't use divs with classes `"container"` and "`col-md-12`". This is just a suggestion.

The fastest way to solve your problem, is to rewrite the next css:

```
.nav > li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - That helped me with the navigation bar. But when scrolling the affix is working but the nav bar becomes transparent and i'm not able to use it.

Comment: It is not transparent. It is behind the body content. The next class rewritten wrong "#nav.affix". Add "z-index:1030;". This should be there from bootstrap.

Comment: How can i add a smooth animation for it?